# Page not working in href link

Tags: jquery, html-framework-7

I have used the latest framework7 version 1.6.4

When I click the `a` link it doesn't work to redirect the page and I also tried in onclick event, but that does not work too.

This is my code:

```
<li>
   <a href="document.html" class="item-link item-content">
      <div class="item-media"><i class="ion-ios-upload"></i> </div>
      <div class="item-inner">
         <div class="item-title"><span>Document Upload</span></div>
      </div>
   </a>
</li>
```

Note: I have also tried in tag page navigation which didn't work as well.

How to fix this? Can you give any example code?

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"? nothing happen or page error?

Comment: I have tried the href="./document.html" but page will not move

Comment: framework7 version 1.6.4 is this problem to not working on href link

Comment: Pls tell me the solution

Answer (score 0):

Change your href like this `href="./document.html"`

Answer (score 0):

document.html is in the same folder as this file from where you are calling this?
If no then give proper link till that file

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that when linking to a href page in Framework7, you need to add some javascript to your "myapp.js", or the name of your F7 app js file. [PagesinFramework7Reference](https://framework7.io/docs/pages.html)

So, as in the documentation:

There are two ways to add page events handler (to "myapp.js":

```
// Option 1. Using one 'page:init' handler for all pages (recommended way):
$$(document).on('page:init', function (e) {
  // Do something here when page loaded and initialized

})

// Option 2. Using live 'page:init' event handlers for each page (not recommended)
$$(document).on('page:init', '.page[data-page="about"]', function (e) {
  // Do something here when page with data-page="about" attribute loaded and initialized
})
```

This worked just fine for me when I linked from a list item. Take a look at the documentation on pages to see if it will help you.